# Anagram Function Returning None

Tags: python, function, file, if-statement, for-loop

I have to make a program that calls a function and searches for all the anagrams of the string from a file, returning a list of the words.

I made everything and it should work, but when I start it it gives me `None`. I even tried words that are in the file and it is the same.

```
def find_anagrams_in_wordlist(str, str_list):
    str_list = get_dictionary_wordlist()    

    for int in range (0, len(str)):
        anagram(str, str_list[int])
        if anagram(str, str_list[int]):
            return(str_list[int])

def find_anagrams(str):
    str_list = get_dictionary_wordlist()

    return find_anagrams_in_wordlist(str, str_list)

def test_find_anagrams():
    print(find_anagrams("tenato"))
```

And this is my `anagram()` function:

```
def anagram(str1, str2):
    str1_list = list(str1)
    str1_list.sort()
    str2_list = list(str2)
    str2_list.sort()

    return (str1_list == str2_list)
```

And this is my `get_dictionary_wordlist()` function:

```
def get_dictionary_wordlist(): 
    text_file = open("dictionary.txt", "r") 
    return text_file.read().splitlines()
```

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Fix the indent please?

Comment: @KevinGuan What should I fix?

Comment: Here is the [edit] link, just edit your question and fix it :). Check the incorrect code indent.

Comment: I made some changes, is it enough?

Comment: Yes!  Now looks good, thanks.  :)

Comment: def get_dictionary_wordlist():
 text_file = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
 
 return text_file.read().splitlines()

Comment: Could you give an example of your `dictionary.txt` please? Remember use [edit] link instead of comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets examine what you have:

```
def find_anagrams_in_wordlist(str, str_list):  # You shouldn't name something 'str' because it's a type.
    str_list = get_dictionary_wordlist()  # You are overwriting your incoming list with the same function call.

    for int in range (0, len(str)):  # You're executing your for loop once per letter in the candidate word.
        anagram(str, str_list[int])  # This function executes but isn't doing anything
        if anagram(str, str_list[int]):
            return(str_list[int])  # If you find something you are exiting your for loop AND your function

def anagram(str1, str2):
    str1_list = list(str1)
    str1_list.sort()  # The result of this is the same every time... and it's None
    str2_list = list(str2)
    str2_list.sort()  # Always returns None

    return (str1_list == str2_list)  # This is the only real work being done here.
```

Finally, you are not actually accumulating your results:

```
def find_anagrams_in_wordlist(candidate, word_list):  # Name your variables clearly
    results = list()  # For accumulating your results
    sorted_candidate = sorted(candidate)  # You only need to sort your candidate once
    for word in word_list:  # This is the cleanest way to loop through an iterable
        sorted_word = sorted(word)  # Sort the word once
        if sorted_candidate == sorted_word:  # Now check for equality: an additional function can obfuscate things
            results.append(word)  # If it's equal, add it to your results
    return results  # Send back your results
```

We can test it like so, in the REPL:

```
>>> lst = {"cat", "dog", "fish", "god"}
>>> find_anagrams_in_wordlist("odg", lst)
['god', 'dog']
>>> find_anagrams_in_wordlist("cat", lst)
['cat']
>>> find_anagrams_in_wordlist("shif", lst)
['fish']
>>> find_anagrams_in_wordlist("birds", lst)
[]
```

Note that in my solution I am using `sorted` not `sort()`. `sort()` won't accomplish the correct thing:

```
>>> x = "moonshot"
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y
['m', 'o', 'o', 'n', 's', 'h', 'o', 't']
>>> z = y.sort()
>>> z
>>> type(z)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> sorted(x)
['h', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 's', 't']
```

Comment: ` results = list()` is said that ti is **unindent does not match any outer indentation level**

Comment: When i tried your code and there is a problem with the `results = list()`, in the cmd it is said that code is **unindent does not match any outer indentation level**

Comment: I am trying to do it with my fail that the programme should search for anagrams there that are anagrams to the string. Here it is: 
`def find_anagrams_in_wordlist(str, str_list):
 str_list = get_dictionary_wordlist() 
    results = list()
    sorted_str = list(str).sort()

    for word in str_list:
       sorted_word = list(word).sort()
       if sorted_str == sorted_word:
           results.append(word)
  return results`

Comment: Please note that `list(word).sort()` returns `None`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94999/discussion-between-trex00-and-nathaniel-ford).

Answer (score 1):

OK, first guess; this code:

```
def find_anagrams_in_wordlist(str, str_list):
    str_list = get_dictionary_wordlist()    

    for int in range (0, len(str)):
        anagram(str, str_list[int])
        if anagram(str, str_list[int]):
            return(str_list[int])
```

is working with `range(0, len(str))` - the number of characters in 'tenato' - instead of `range(0, len(str_list))` - the number of words in the dictionary.

This means you only test the first few dictionary words, and ignore the rest. Try it as:

```
def find_anagrams_in_wordlist(str, str_list):
    str_list = get_dictionary_wordlist()    

    for word in str_list:
        if anagram(str, word):
            return word
```

(there's no need to count through lists in Python using range(), you can `for item in mylist:` directly).

NB. if this works, your design will still only return the first word which matches, not a list of words which match. You would need to build up a list of matches, and then return the list after the loop completes.

Comment: Oh, it works. Thanks for the help. It only displays the first word, so I need to make a for loop befor the loop that is searching for the word? or not

Comment: No. Rather than return `word` add it to a list and keep the `for` loop going. Also, note that you only need sort your `str1` once, and pass that list in to the `anagram` function.

Comment: I used 'return list(word)' and it separated the letters of the first word.